# c# wpf MediaElement black flash

Tags: c#, wpf

When MediaElement starts playing video it shows like a black frame for a moment. Here is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="MediaElementTest.MainWindow" /* */
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Red">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window> 

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NextState();
    }

    public void NextState()
    {
        var content = new VideoState();
        contentControl.Content = content;
    }
}
```

And

```
<UserControl x:Class="MediaElementTest.VideoState" /* */
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement x:Name="videoPlayer" MediaEnded="videoPlayer_MediaEnded" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

public partial class VideoState : UserControl
{
    public VideoState()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        videoPlayer.Source = new Uri("C:\\wpf\\bin\\Debug\\data\\start.mp4");
        //videoPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100); //!!! WORKS FINE WITH IT
        videoPlayer.Play();
    }

    private void videoPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoPlayer.Source = null;
        videoPlayer = null;
        GC.Collect();

        MainWindow wnd = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
        wnd.NextState();
    }
}
```

If I set videoPlayer.Position to like 100 milliseconds it works fine. How can I get rid of this black frame. I've tried to set `ScrubbingEnabled="true"`and do something like :

```
videoPlayer.Play();
videoPlayer.Pause();
videoPlayer.Play();
```

But there is no difference and black popup still occurs. If I set videoPlayer.Position to 0ms at mediaEnded event and play it works also fine. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I had the issue as you did, but I used your hardcoded solution, putting the video a little forward "videoPlayer.Position to like 100 milliseconds" and I am satisfied, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get the Loaded event of your User Control and move the below code in the handler of Loaded event in your User control's code behind file

```
videoPlayer.Source = new Uri("C:\\wpf\\bin\\Debug\\data\\start.mp4");
videoPlayer.Play();
```

Once the VideoState user control is properly loaded as the content of your window, only then you execute further logic to play the video. I hope that it will solve the black screen problem.